# View all REST API routes of my Magento 2

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am looking for the url which will show all the available API REST routes. I have seen it before, which outputted some json. I just can't recall the url nor can't I find the right information. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Please help me out when I am trying to create customer account by rest api in magento2 then I am getting error in postman, please suggest me how to resolve it, please help me , Thank you for advance [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrBO.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrBO.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Magento Commerce for B2B Generate a local REST API reference**

- The **REST** documentation on the **Magento devdocs** website is generated
  with [Swagger UI](https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/) using a schema derived from the latest build of
  Magento 2.
- However, the REST API documentation on devdocs is static    in that
  the Magento Developers website is not running an instance of
  Magento, and there is no live data.

  http:///swagger
- By default, Magento returns documentation for resources available to
  anonymous users. If you specify a valid value in the api_key text box
  in the upper right corner, Swagger returns documentation for all the
  APIs the user has access to. To generate an API key, call the **POST**
  `/V1/integration/customer/token` or **POST** `/V1/integration/admin/token` as
  directed in Token-based authentication.
- The generated Swagger documentation provides the capability to test
  **REST API** requests. A user can enter a sample request, then press the
  Try it out! button, and Swagger returns information such as a curl
  command, a request URL, a response body, a response code, and the
  response header. The Try it out! button will not work unless a bearer
  **authorization** token has been specified.

  > https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

  [ base url: /index.php/rest/default , api version: 2.2 ]

**Updated**

```
domain.com/rest/all/schema?services=all
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually meant https://domain.com/rest/all/schema?services=all, which is used by Swagger to generate the documentation. My bet.

Comment: Ohh :D okay, let me update the same for future reference :)

Comment: @AdityaShah Can we show to some specific user (admin or customer) some specific custom APIs and hide the remaining APIs from Swagger UI ?

Comment: why api gets "all" added in it self ? http://localhost/magento2/rest/all/V1/wishlist/1